# CvSVM does not train when svm_type is NU_SVC

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I am extracting SURF feature descriptors from face images. 
Num of Classes = 29 (So class_labels in trainingData are from 1-29)
Num of training images = 3000+

I want to use CvSVM::NU_SVC in OpenCV 2.4.8 to train SVM classifier on the 64-D feature vectors.

But when I call the "train" function, it returns "false". Basically, it doesnt do the training.

I followed a procedure very similar to 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't think OpenCV's SVM directly supports multi-class problems. You'd probably have to use "one-against-all" scheme.

Comment: ^^ multi-class *is* possible, but you have to tweak your value for 'nu' then, it will return silently, if that was deemed unacceptable. try something in the order of 1/numclasses

Comment: I really appreciate your responses a-Jays and berak!
Just to give some more details:
I divide the face image into a virtual mxn grid (G). The features (eg:SURF) from each grid (g_ij) are used to train the corresponding SVM classifier h_ij for all 29 classes.
So in total, I have m*n SVM classifiers for the Face.

But the opencv example for svm seems to be supporting multiclass. When I try NU-SVC with upto 3 classes, it works.


My grid is 3x6. So i have 18 SVMs. I tried your approach and here is what I got:
what I observe is that some of the SVMs get trained, while others dont.